# Cloudfoundry-UAA for SCDF Kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow, cloudfoundry-uaa

This question may seem dumb. But still asking as I couldn't narrow down the proper solution. I have the scdf running in openshift platform. I'm trying to set up the authentication and authorization mechanisms as per Security section given in [spring-cloud-dataflow](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.5.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-security) documentation.

Could the same documentation be used for kubernetes as well ? Because I see some notes like it's specific for cloudfoundry and no mention of kubernetes was found in security section.

Answer (score 0):

> Could the same documentation be used for kubernetes as well ? Because I see some notes like it's specific for cloudfoundry and no mention of kubernetes was found in security section.

No, the current UAA documentation setup is **only** for Cloud Foundry. The UAA support for Kubernetes is TBD.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have to add some authentication mechanisms before any user accessing scdf dashboard deployed in kubernetes. Any suggestions or Is there any documentations you can point me to Ilayaperumal?